# Historical stock prices download in R

Tags: r

I would like to download historical stock prices (daily) of Chinese based companies (which are listed on the US stock market e.g. NASDAQ) into R.

Therefore, i have found a list of companies (on NASDAQ)

```
stockprice <- c("YI","VNET","QFIN","JOBS","ATV","AMCN","BABA","ACH","AMBO","ATAI","JG","BIDU","BZUN","BI","LI","BCAC","BCACR","BCACU","BCACW","BITA","BRQS","BEDU","CSIQ","CBAT","CYOU","CADC","CAAS","GLG","CBPO","CCCL","CCRC","DL","CEA","JRJC","CGA","HGSH","CIFS","CJJD","LFC","BORN","COE","SNP","CPHI","CREG","ZNH","SXTC","CNTF","CHA","CXDC","CCIH","CNET","CLPS","CMSS","CMSSR","CMSSU","CMSSW","CCM","CTRP","DQ","DTSS","DOGZ","LYL","DXF","EHIC","EVK","SFUN","FANH","FAMI","FORK","FTFT","FFHL","GDS","DNJR","GLAC","GLACR","GLACU","GLACW","GRNQ","GSUM","GSH","GURE","HLG","HEBT","HX","HPJ","HOLI","HMI","HNP","HTHT","IQ","ITP","JD","JKS","JMU","KNDI","KBSF","KGJI","LX","LLIT","LITB","LOAC","LOACR","LOACU","LOACW","LKCO","MDJH","MTC","MOMO","MOXC","NTP","NTES","EDU","NEWA","NIU","NOAH","SEED","OSN","PTR","FENG","PDD","PME","PT","PLAG","PHCF","QD","QTT","RCON","SOL","BIQI","RENN","RETO","REDU","SECO","SMI","AIHS","SGOC","TYHT","SINA","SHI","SVA","SOHU","SORL","SPI","SSLJ","TAL","TANH","TAOP","TEDU","PETZ","NCTY","TMSR","TC","TOUR","UTSI","UXIN","VIOT","VIPS","WB","WINS","XIN","XNET","YIN","YRD","YY","ZLAB","ZKIN","ZTO") %>%
tq_get(get  = "stock.prices",
       from = "2014-01-01",
       to   = "2018-12-31") %>%
group_by(symbol) %>%
tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
             mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
             period     = "daily", 
             col_rename = "stockprice")
```

Problem #1
I would like to have the table ordered by date and each company in a seperate column (not row!).

Problem #2
These companies were not listed over the same time frame (some of them shorter than 5 years).
How can I "clean" the table and add "zero" for missing values?

(maybe) Problem #3
The aim is to get each stock return which should be 
*100 x (log(P_t) - log(P_t-1))*
Hence, the log of the price today minus log of the price yesterday, times 100.

I have no idea if that happened by "*mutate_fun = periodReturn*" .

I tried also other codes, but the above got closest to an output..

Answer (score 0):

If X is the result of the code in the question (after fixing it -- it currently does not work as posted) then this can all be done in one statement (giving a multivariate zoo series):

```
read.zoo(X, index = "date", split = "symbol")
```